# Objects assignment and GC behavior in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given code below. What is the final value of the object `objectOfA_In_B` ?

```
Class A 
{
    // Some parameters and method with complicated logic goes here
}


Class B
{
    A objectOfA_In_B = new A();

    B()
    {
     // Operation done on objectOfA
    }

    public A getObjectA()
    {
        return objectOfA_In_B;
    }   
}


Class C
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            A objectOfA_In_C = null;
            B objectOfB = new B();

            objectOfA_In_C = B.getObjectA()

            // Rest of logic goes here
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            objectOfA_In_C = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question is:** Will `objectOfA_In_B` be `null` as well by setting `objectOfA_In_C` to `null` in finally block of `C`'s main method simply because they are pointting to the same object ? Are both `objectOfA_In_C` and `objectOfA_In_B` are ready to get collected from Garbage Collector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will objectOfA_In_B be null as well by setting objectOfA_In_C to null
>   in finally block of C's main method simply because they are pointting
>   to the same object ?

No, Java is pass by value. Even references to objects are passed by value. So, by setting `objectOfA_In_C` to `null`, `objectOfA_In_B` wont become null.

> Are both objectOfA_In_C and objectOfA_In_B are ready to get collected
>   from Garbage Collector

There is only one instance of `A` in question here and 2 references pointing to it (one of which is set to `null` in the `finally` block). That instance will be ready for GC when there will be no references pointing to it.Note that `objectOfA_In_B` still points to that instance.

Comment: So if  variable `objectOfA_In_B` is set to `null` in `B` then the only object created of `A` will be ready to get collected by GC. Correct ?

Comment: @Salman - Yes, if there are no references to an object, then it will be eligible for GC. You could override `finalize()` and *may be*, you can see the behavior yourself

Comment: @TheLostMind - *maybe* you can see the behavior.  There are various confounding factors that could mean that you do not observe what you would expect to observe.

Comment: @StephenC - Yes. You are right. There should be a "may be" there. Updated my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two variables here and only one object. Either of the variables can point to the object or not. An assignment to a variable has no effect on other variables. The object (not the variables) is ready for garbage collection when no variable points to it. Variables cannot be garbage collected, only objects can.

(Since this looks like homework, I left some conclusions to be made by you, since you want to learn. :))

Comment: It is not a homework. It is memory leak problem in production environment :P

Comment: Can you take a heap dump of the leaking process? If yes, loading it into the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool will show you the cause of the leak.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be `null`since you assign `null` just to the local reference. That won't change any reference that may point to that object. So `objectOf_A_In_B`is not affected and therefore not ready to be collected by the GC